# Run Odata Web Service

Tags: c#, odata

I've put a Odata API together, using Entity Framework. It has 3 Projects, API itself, Model and Persistence. I know how to run it through VS (2015). My startup project is API, wich requires the other two. [I've found how to build those three projects into one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613654/build-two-vs2010-c-projects-into-the-same-output-folder).

[image]

Now here's the question:

How can I run the Program? There are a bunch of .dll and .xml Files in the build folder, but no .exe. I suppose I'll have to run it through a Webserver, but how?

Answer (score 0):

> I've found how to build those three projects into one folder.

You don't need to. Compiling a .NET application will put all required and referenced assemblies in the startup program's `bin` folder.

> How can I run the Program?

Hit F5. This will start the Api project's configured web server, either the ASP.NET Development Server or IIS Express (or custom web server).

If you want to *deploy* the application, publish the Api application to a web server, for example to IIS. See [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

Comment: I know the way to run it trhough VS, would be hard to test otherwise. I'll have a look at that link, that will take it's time. Thanks.